# relation "branches" does not exist pgbench-tools and postgresql database scale returned ""

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, testing, pgpool

I've installed postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu 12.04 with pgpoolII-3.3.3 and pgPoolAdmin.

I'm trying to make a test with pgbench-tools to measure the performance of postgresql.

So I move to the directory where is pgbench-tools and configure the config file.

I try to execute this order:

```
sudo -u postgres ./runset
```

After this it appears a message "Removing old pgbench tables"

First error message (seems not to be important) is: `ERROR: table "accounts does not exist"`

After this it appears a message: `VACUUM creating new pgbench tables`

After this

```
creating tables
10000 tuples done
20000 tuples done
...
100000 tuples done
...
vacuum...done.
Run set #1 of 2 with 2 clients scale=1
Running tests using: psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 pgbench
Storing results using: psql -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432 pgbench
```

And after this it comes "the crash":

```
ERROR: relation "branches" does not exist
LINE 1: select count(*) for branches
ERROR: Attempt to determine database scale returned "", aborting
```

This maybe a stupid issue and I'm not being able to solve it as I don't have a high level of knowledge on those systems.

Any idea about what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the tables "accounts" and "branches" refer to the table names in pgbench shipped with Postgres 8.3 and older. It has been changed to pgbench_* after that. So I was facing a version mismatch of pgbench-tools. Solved after downloading pgbench tools from github https://github.com/gregs1104/pgbench-tools